# android studio 3.0 Canary 1 View.GONE and View.VISIBLE show error

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I use `View.GONE` to setVisibility but Android studio 3.0 canary tips "Must be one of `View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE, View.VISIBLE"`

Comment: Make sure you have correctly imported `android.view.View`.

Comment: this code in old version Android studio is ok

Comment: I'm having the same problem!  Did you find a solution?

Comment: can you post the whole code. Or [open an issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192750&template=0) and attach a sample or your project